# Project Euler 11

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble with my [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=11) code in Python -- When I run through the code in my head everything seems to check out, but I'm still getting the wrong answer. I'm really new to Python, so it could be any number of things. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
nums = '\
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08\n\
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00\n\
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65\n\
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91\n\
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80\n\
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50\n\
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70\n\
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21\n\
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72\n\
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95\n\
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92\n\
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57\n\
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58\n\
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40\n\
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66\n\
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69\n\
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36\n\
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16\n\
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54\n\
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48'

grid = []
diag = []

for line in nums.split('\n'):
    grid.append(map(int, line.split(' ')))

i=0
j=0

while i<17:
    l = grid[i][j]*grid[i+1][j+1]*grid[i+2][j+2]*grid[i+3][j+3]
    diag.append(l)
    i+=1    
    if i==17:
        j+=1
        i=0
        l = grid[i][j]*grid[i+1][j+1]*grid[i+2][j+2]*grid[i+3][j+3]
        diag.append(l)
    if j==16:
        break
print max(diag)
```

Comment: What do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: Current output is 40304286, should be 70600674

Comment: The question reads that you must check up, down, left and diagonal -- you are only checking diagonals.

Comment: Oh, wow - Can't believe I missed that. I'll write it out to check the up and down too. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

My comments are more along the lines of code review, but culminating in a full solution:

You can get rid of those ugly endline escapes with the textwrap module (implicit string concatenation would work too, but it would mean more repetitious typing and clutter):

```
import textwrap

nums = textwrap.dedent('''\
    08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
    49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
    81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
    52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
    22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
    24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
    32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
    67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
    24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
    21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
    78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
    16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
    86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
    19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
    04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
    88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
    04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
    20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
    20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
    01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48''')



grid = []
```

Use the string builtin method, `splitlines`, and list comprehensions are somewhat more readable than map (as well as not needing to be wrapped with a list call to be forward compatible with Python 3):

```
for line in nums.splitlines():
    grid.append([int(i) for i in line.split(' ')])
```

Now we have our data, and we can begin our search algorithm. Since the horizontals are already in rows together, we can easily search by row, and since `zip` stops on the shortest iterable, we can safely zip up slices of the same string starting at increasing points from the beginning without getting index errors:

```
def max_horizontal(grid):
    return max(w * x * y * z
               for r in grid
               for w, x, y, z in zip(r, r[1:], r[2:], r[3:]))
```

Vertical is not much more tricky, but we want to transpose it like it was a matrix, and then we can use the same code around it. Expanding an iterable of iterables into `zip` is the same as transposing such a matrix that we can iterate over:

```
def max_vertical(grid):
    return max(w * x * y * z
               for c in zip(*grid)
               for w, x, y, z in zip(c, c[1:], c[2:], c[3:]))
```

Diagonals are a bit more difficult, but if we get one definition right, we just reverse it. Here, we need to go row by row over a window across the matrix, so we treat the matrix like we treated the row with `zip`. So we step over the matrix one row at a time, looking at 4 rows each time. Next, using the slash semantic to indicate the diagonal running from bottom left to top right, in our first row, we start at the fourth element (keeping in mind, Python starts indexing at 0, so that corresponds to the [3:] slice notation below), second row, 3rd element, third row, second element, 4th row, the first element. Again, since `zip` stops at the end of the shortest iterable, our window doesn't run out of range of the matrix:

```
def max_slashdiag(g=grid):
    return max(w * x * y * z
               for r1, r2, r3, r4 in zip(g, g[1:], g[2:], g[3:])
               for w, x, y, z in zip(r1[3:], r2[2:], r3[1:], r4))
```

To get the other diagonal, just reverse the corresponding row starting points:

```
def max_backdiag(g=grid):
    return max(w * x * y * z
               for r1, r2, r3, r4 in zip(g, g[1:], g[2:], g[3:])
               for w, x, y, z in zip(r1, r2[1:], r3[2:], r4[3:]))
```

And we take the maximum of all of these functions:

```
max(max_horizontal(grid), 
    max_vertical(grid), 
    max_slashdiag(g=grid), 
    max_backdiag(g=grid))
```

which returns `70600674`